# Llamado a Mongodb y filtrar resultados con Nodejs en funcion del tiempo

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Estoy aprendiendo un poco de programación y me encuentro creando una aplicación que muestre los resultados cargados por un sensor de temperatura. El sensor registra la temperatura en la base de datos cada 30 segundos. Estos resultados los estoy visualizando en un gráfico de linea. Desde NodeJS, en una de las rutas solicito la informacion con la siguiente llamada a la base de datos. `const mediciones = await Mediciones.find().sort({ dia: -1 }).limit(120).lean();` Con el limit 120, lo que consigo es que me grafique únicamente la ultima hora de mediciones. Si quisiera graficar las ultimas 24hs podría cambiar el limit por 2880 para asi traer todas las mediciones de las ultimas 24hs, esto no es optimo para los gráficos ya que tomaría muchísimos puntos de referencia. Cual seria la forma de llamar a la base de datos y que traiga un solo dato por ejemplo de cada media hora? Para poder graficarlo de una forma mas bonita sin que se desborde de información el gráfico. Muchas gracias!

El schema es:

```
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const MedicionesSchema = new Schema({
temperatura: {type: Number, required: true},
dia: {type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Mediciones', MedicionesSchema)
```

Comment: Hola. Es facil, pero puedes mostrar cual es tu esquema? Para ver como almacenas los datos.

Comment: Ahi agregue el schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando en cuenta que deseas filtrar una vez que tienes los resultados, es fácil usando [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter).

Como tu consulta devuelve un tipo [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array), aplicaremos sobre el mismo un filtro para seleccionar equitativamente la cantidad de documentos que deseamos representar en el gráfico.

Dices que si deseas las mediciones de las últimas 24 horas realizas la siguiente consulta:

```
const mediciones = await Mediciones.find().sort({ dia: -1 }).limit(2880).lean();
```

Las mediciones han sido registradas cada 30 segundos en la base de datos. Eso es 2 mediciones por minuto. Por lo tanto las últimas 24 horas representa un total de 2880 mediciones.

Ahora, debemos definir cuantas mediciones deseas mostrar en tu gráfica.

Supongamos que de esas 2880 mediciones deseo tomar 30 mediciones separadas equitativamente unas de otras. Es decir que de la cantidad de elementos disponibles (2880), tomo 30 elementos, de tal forma que entre una medición y otra hay exactamente la misma cantidad de elementos.

De esta forma tendría una reducción de los datos de 2880 a 30.

Si dividimos 2880 entre 30, nos da 96. Por lo tanto debo tomar 1 medición de la lista cada 96 elementos.

Se me ocurre que lo puedes hacer así:

```js
const limit = 2880;
const cantMediciones = 30;

const mediciones = await Mediciones.find().sort({ dia: -1 }).limit(limit).lean();

const filtradas = mediciones.filter((medicion, index) => {
  if(index % (limit/cantMediciones) === 0) {
    return medicion;
  }
});

console.log(filtradas.length); // <= 30
```

Como puedes ver, en el método `filter` devolveré una medición sólo cuando su posición (`index`) sea divisible exactamente por 96 (`limit/cantMediciones`).

Esto nos devolverá las 30 mediciones espaciadas equitativamente a lo largo de la lista.

Espero que con esto puedas resolver el problema planteado.

Comment: muchisimas gracias! exactamente como lo esperaba.

Comment: se podra hacer lo mismo pero desde la llamada de la base de datos?

Comment: Por supuesto que se puede hacer, usando una agregación o un procedimiento `map-reduce`. Puedo editar mi respuesta y agregar eso.